# Options for recovering user data off of unrooted Motorola Android in boot loop

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop, data-recovery, motorola

My phone started to boot loop*. It is a Motorola Droid Turbo (xt1254) running Android 6.0.1, and this is a snippet from the recovery screen:

> Device is LOCKED. Status Code: 0
>
> Software status: Official
>
> Connect USB Data Cable

From the recovery mode, it gives these options:

- Reboot system now
- Reboot to bootloader
- Apply update from ADB
- Apply update from SD card
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition
- Mount /System
- View recovery logs
- Power off

qe 0/0

Supported API: 3

Wiping the cache partition had no effect, the boot loop remained, however would any of the above options allow me to transfer data to a PC over usb with the ADB. Or are there any services that can read the flash memory?

I should note that I got this phone from the Verizon store and had never rooted it nor installed custom recovery software, however I may have enabled developer options at some point.

*The boot loop sequence is this:

- Motorola Logo Bright
- Vibrates
- Motorola Logo Dim
- Full-screen startup animation with sound
- Black background with white box saying: Optimizing App 1 of 14
- then over the next few seconds to: Optimizing App 14 of 14 (although I have way more than 14 apps)
- Then white box says: Starting Apps
- Then Motorola Logo Dim for a moment
- Startup animation for a moment
- Black screen
- Repeats

To get out of it, I go into recovery mode and do power off. There were a few possible events that may have precipitated this, and there's no way of knowing which one, these are:

1. Phone has been (accidentally) dropped twice recently, although in protective casing. The actual phone performance wasn't effected, however there seemed have been an effect on battery performance (required more frequent charging and battery seemed to drain more rapidly when the phone was in use). Also, the second drop was hard enough that when I took the phone out of the protective casing, a small piece of the casing had come off, although there was no visible damage to the phone such as cracks or screen cracks or anything like that and the phone was completely functional as far as I could tell, afterwards. However, it was after the battery ran down after this second drop when the phone entered a boot-loop. Is it possible there was internal damage that prevented it from booting, such as a hardware check failing, or memory damage or something like that?
2. I don't update apps very often, however I just updated some apps (perhaps the cause for the app optimization card during boot) before this happened. I've seen in some posts that there can be problematic apps that interfere with system files and may cause this.
3. During the last use, I watched a video on an app, fell asleep and found through that app's history on another device that it had autoplayed through an approximate 4 hr playlist .. before running out of battery and to run into the boot-loop after I had partially charged it (afterwards before trying the cache wipe, I charged it to 100%). Perhaps this had overburdened the device in some way or filled up its memory- the app is supposed to stream, however maybe it downloaded - I've seen some posts that say that if the memory is completely full, it could cause this.
4. This is unrelated, but thought I would include it anyhow: when there was a mandatory Verizon/OS update (a while ago 24.91.5.quark_verizon.verizon.en.us), it was initially stuck on the Motorola logo after the update. Fortunately, holding the power key to reboot again it was able to boot.